# Immutable.js Map set vs update

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I would like to change a value at a key in a Map I have. Other than the fact that using `update` will give me an error if the key I ask to update doesn't exist, what benefit is there (if any) to using `update` over `set`? I find `set` to be significantly more concise/cleaner. In fact, based on the documentation one could (blindly) argue that `set` is actually more efficient than `update` since `set` doesn't have to perform the `get` for the `updater` function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`update` is more powerful when your new value is the result of a transform of the current value:

```
const inc = (x) => (x + 1)
const m = Immutable.Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
m.update('b', inc) #=> {a: 1, b: 3, c: 3})
```

vs. with `set`:

```
m.set('b', inc(m.get('b'))
```

This example is pretty trivial, but the pattern of applying transforms to your data in this way becomes more common when you start building your algorithms around your data (as in [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)) instead of the other way around. I’ve done things before in a game like `game.update('player', moveLeft)`.

If you *know* what the new value is, though, then just use `set` as `update(key, x => val)` is rather silly.

Comment: Yeah, I know the value, so was wondering if it was still good practice to use `update` or if `set` was fine.

Answer (score 4):

@MatthewHerbst said:

> (...) was wondering if it was still good practice to use update or if set was fine

in his comment on @andrew-marshall's response

I don't think it is a question of good or bad practice.

From what i understand there are two different use cases:

1. the value you set **does NOT depend** on the previous value : use `set`
2. the value you set **depends** on the previous value: use `update`

So you I don't think you should always use `set` over `update` (or the other way around), I think *you should use one or the other depending on your use case*